# How to adjust width of bootstrap combobox as per screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I had a dropdown (select) which I converted into combobox using [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21368/bootstrap-combobox/index.html).

Before converting select into combobox, select was looking as I wanted,
but after applying `class="combo"`, my dropdown/combo is getting break.

Before:

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel_blg" name="bldg"  ><option value="17">AOB</option><option value="18">Vasant Vihar</option></select>
```

Displaying properly here.

After applying CSS class combobox:

```
<select class="combobox" id="sel_blg" name="bldg"  ><option value="17">AOB</option><option value="18">Vasant Vihar</option></select>
```

Not displaying combobox properly as per my screen width.

Comment: I have a hunch that the `.combobox` class is going to cause problems for you unless you're referencing it in the CSS as `..combobox`.  You should change it to `combobox`.  Can you post your CSS?